# Mounting NTFS partition by fstab at boot still works correctly, but process never dies

Tags: linux-mint, mount, fstab, ntfs

Why would a `mount.ntfs` operation never finish (continue to burn CPU) if the partition seems to be correctly mounted? How could this be debugged?

On Linux Mint 19.3, I've had an fstab (below) operating correctly for a long time. It mounts an NTFS data partition I share with windows. I haven't used windows in a while, and it is definitely not hibernating. At boot, it correctly mounts the drive (and binds certain folders), and I can access all the data. It fully seems to be working, as usual, but this is the point where I can't find any other reference online.

After logging in, after boot, root process `mount.ntfs` continues to burn / consume a core's worth of CPU usage. I can't figure out what's causing it (since it seems to have already mounted), but the process does come from the fstab: `cat /proc/[id of mount.ntfs process]/cmdline`: `/sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sda7 /mnt/DATA -o rw,noatime,locale=en_US.utf8,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000`.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=xxxx-xxxx  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx none            swap    sw              0       0
# Data Partition, on /dev/sda7
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /mnt/DATA ntfs noatime,defaults,locale=en_US.utf8,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000    0   2
# Bind directories correctly
/mnt/DATA/Downloads                 /home/me/Downloads  none    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
/mnt/DATA/Desktop/LinDesktop        /home/me/Desktop    none    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
/mnt/DATA/Documents                 /home/me/Documents  none    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
/mnt/DATA/Media/Music               /home/me/Music      none    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
/mnt/DATA/Media/Pictures            /home/me/Pictures   auto    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
/mnt/DATA/Media/Videos              /home/me/Videos     auto    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
/mnt/DATA/Workspace                 /home/me/Workspace  auto    bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/DATA       0   0
```

Looking at the strace, it seems to be making write & reads successfully... for what that's worth.

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 30.51    1.392332           3    518018           pread64
 26.86    1.225702           3    416749           pwrite64
 18.16    0.828499           4    232782         1 writev
 15.72    0.717149           3    236584           read
  7.22    0.329389          86      3846           fsync
  0.98    0.044537           3     15188           sendto
  0.55    0.025258           2     15188           getpid
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    4.562866               1438355         1 total
```

The only error I could find for mounting (in syslog/dmesg) was just to re-mount root / at boot time, long before mounting other drives: `[    4.155258] EXT4-fs (sda9): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro` 
Edit (Moving comments with more info up here):

If I comment out the mounts in fstab and reboot, it only hangs after the user login. (Had to drop to root shell to re-enable mounting from boot). `umount -av` would say that /mnt/DATA is busy and could not be unmounted. I think this issue is also why I can't suspend, because 1 process (this) refuses to sleep.

umount will suggest (from tab complete) /mnt/DATA as a mount to target, but if I kill the mount.ntfs process, then it also removes it as a mount to unmount. Now that I look closely, there's a dconf-service that runs with a good chunk of CPU right from the beginning, that I don't know why/what it's doing, that (as said) spikes high if I forcefully kill the mount.ntfs process.

Trying to force unmount `sudo umount -f /mnt/DATA` also reports target is busy; this causes the `mount.ntfs` process to disappear, but makes the `dconf-service` spike hot. Its /proc/cmdline is just `/usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service`; I don't know how to get more info on what it's actually doing with respect to this problem. This unmount (and other actions) also cause this message to stderr: `fatal: unable to access '/[path to now-broken symlink to drive subfolder]': Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: Does it happen if your run mount from console? I.e. `umount -a && mount /mnt/DATA` ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I commented out the mounts in fstab and rebooted, but it would hang after the user login. (Dropped to root shell to re-enable mounting from boot). `umount -av` would say that /mnt/DATA is busy and could not be unmounted. I think this issue is also why I can't suspend, because 1 process (this) refuses to sleep.

Comment: Trying to force unmount `sudo umount -f /mnt/DATA` also reports target is busy; this caused the `mount.ntfs` process to disappear, but now there's a `dconf-service` that's running hot who's /proc/cmdline is `/usr/lib/dconf/dconf-servicefatal: unable to access '/[path to now-broken symlink to drive subfolder]': Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: umount will suggest (from tab complete) /mnt/DATA as a mount to target, but if I kill the mount.ntfs process, then it also removes it as a mount to unmount. Now that I look closely, there's a `dconf-service` that runs with a good chunk of CPU right from the beginning, that I don't know why/what it's doing, that (as said) spikes high if I forcefully kill the mount.ntfs process.

Comment: dconf seems to be a unified database of application settings (https://askubuntu.com/q/22313). Do you think you have any applications running, that would be modifying these settings? P.S: Please add the extra info to the question itself, as comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Good point about the comments, I started thinking that myself. As for dconf, looking into that more, I still have no clue; hundreds of applications use it, I can't really image (or know how to filter) to figure out which would cause it. Querying dconf schemas has mostly app layer / app configs, not OS. I'm doing all this debugging on full-shutdown -> powerup cycles (because of these processes that won't die), and I don't have any apps running on startup.

Comment: Try commenting out everything related to DATA in fstab, reboot, and again mount manually.

Comment: As noted above, (& just attempted again), that causes it (the LM cinnamon desktop?) to fail after user login, where I can't access any applications or even terminal, and have to drop to root in recovery mode to undo fstab changes. While in root in recovery mode, I can mount normally, but that doesn't seem too useful.